# Choosing vertices by edge weight

Tags: r, graph, igraph, vertex, edges

I have a network with two types of edges, one with `edge$weight=1` and the other `edge$weight=2` (to define different relationships e.g. marriage vs. kinship). I want to choose the neighbors of nodes that are linked by `edge$weight=2`. Then, after getting the vertex names of the neighbors, I will calculate their degree only for `edge$weight=1`.

It seems simple, but the following code does not give the correct neighbor names:

```
V(net)[E(net)[E(net)$weight==2]]
```

Is there another way to get vertex names with respect to the edge type?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? Here are some tips on how to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What if node 'a' links to 'b' with both kind of edges? Or to 'c'? It would be indeed nice to have an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `adj` function which will return the vertices adjacent to a given edge set. In your case you can choose all the relevant vertices by using `V(net)[ adj(E(net)$weight==2) ]`

For example:

```
# make a sample graph with edge weights 1 or 2
net <- graph.full(20)
E(net)$weight <- sample(1:2,ecount(net),replace=T)

# now select only those vertices connected by an edge with weight == 2
V(net)[ adj(E(net)$weight==2) ]
```